# split file using pattern and name each resulting files with the string containing this pattern (perl)

Tags: linux, perl

I have a file with is like this

```
PATTERN1abcdef_abcd_ab
a
b
PATTERN2azerty_az_aze
c
d
```

and I need to split it into smaller files like these:
PATTERN1abcdef_abcd_ab.txt, which contains:

```
PATTERN1abcdef_abcd_ab
a
b
```

and PATTERN2azerty_az_aze.txt, which contains:

```
PATTERN2azerty_az_aze
c
d
```

I found this perl command, which is working fine:

```
perl -n -e '/^PATTERN/ and open FH, ">output_".$n++; print FH;' inputfile.txt
```

except it does not rename the output files with the string containing the pattern. (the files are output_1. for example)

EDIT: Sorry, I made a mistake, the string containing the PATTERN should not be removed from output text files, AND should be the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
perl -n -e '/^PATTERN.*/ and open FH, "$&.txt"; print FH;' inputfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
this command run during few seconds with large file, but produces nothing.. i doesn't work either with inputfile.txt example file.

Comment: Ha yes ! Sorry ! works perfect ! Thank you very much for you two.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the values to get put into files named
PATTERN1(ie that match your pattern).
Then you will want to capture the name in your regex and use it as part of your file name.

```
perl -n -e '/^(PATTERN\d)/ and open(FH, "> $1.txt")and next; print FH;' inputfile.txt
```

Notice I am capturing the pattern inside the () and $1 will hold the value of our match. I also added a next after file opening, otherwise the match would also be included inside the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help !

   perl -n -e '/^(PATTERN\d)/ and open(FH, "> $1.txt")and next; print FH;' input.txt     
is running for awhile (input.txt is 1 Go) but produce nothing.

I removed the 'and next' as I understood from your message, because I want to keep the PATTERN1 in the first line of PATTERN1.txt, it doesn't work either :
   perl -n -e '/^(PATTERN\d)/ and open(FH, "> $1.txt"); print FH;' input.txt

Comment: Sorry, your command works with input.txt example file but for now, doesn't work with my 1Go text file. I'm on it.

I found why it doesn't work. In fact my pattern line could be PATTERNpsks1225s
The length of string is variable and can contain letter, number, or _

Comment: So your pattern would then be /^PATTERN\w+/  would cover your needs.